# Как передать координаты мыши в lParam сообщения WM_LBUTTONDOWN?

Tags: winapi

Как передать координаты мыши в `lParam` с помощью `SendMessage` c сообщением `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`?

Хочу при нажатии правой кнопки мыши на элементе списка посылать сообщение с событием нажатия левой кнопки. Однако у `SendMessage` четвёртый параметр должен быть `DWORD`-ом с координатами курсора.

Как запихнуть две координаты в один `DWORD`?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь макросом [`MAKELPARAM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632661(v=vs.85).aspx) — он принимает в качестве аргументов нижнюю и верхнюю половинки итогового `LPARAM`-а (то есть `DWORD`-а), в которых и надо хранить координаты:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, keys, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
```

Answer (score 0):

В MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms645607(v=vs.85).aspx) написано буквально следующее:
младший WORD из того DWORD'а содержит x-координату, а старший WORD - y-координату

Comment: вопрос не в том как извлечь; как запихнуть две имеющиеся координаты   в DWORD, чтобы впоследствии отправить через SendMessage

Comment: @ЕвгенийКокошко я написал про формат того DWORD'а. При чем тут извлечение?